# Problem with custom primary key in Django

Tags: django, primary-key

In the following model (`Item`) my goal is to define a customized object ID explicitly when saving. I'm using Django 1.2.5 and sqlite.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, blank=True, max_length=8)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.id = "%s-%s" % (self.group.id, self.group.item_set.count() + 1)
        super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I have the problem that using the admin interface for Item model, when I'm going to save an object that already exists, instead of update the existing record a new record is created. I tried to force the update when appropriate with this code

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    update = bool(self.id)
    self.id = "%s-%s" % (self.group.id, self.group.item_set.count() + 1)
    super(Item, self).save(force_update=update, *args, **kwargs)
```

but without success. Now saving after a change triggers this other problem:

```
DatabaseError at /admin/type/catalog/1_3/

Forced update did not affect any rows.
```

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong and if there is a way to solve the issue.

Thanks

-- EDIT -- (need more help!)

**Use case.**

I want to obtain that when a category is selected, only the items that belongs to that category are shown in the items select box.

For this reason I need to associate each item to the corresponding category using the id field, so that categories and items in the admin interface, if together in the same page, would be relationated by their id (and thus easily handled using jQuery). This way:

```
<select id="id_category" name="category">
  <option value="1">color</option>
  <option value="2">car</option>
</select>

<select id="id_item" name="item">
  <option value="1_1">red</option>
  <option value="1_2">blue</option>
  <option value="2_1">audi</option>
</select>
```

If I would use another field but id, combobox in admin would be totally unrelated in respecet if their id, because item select would be:

```
  <option value="1">red</option>
  <option value="2">blue</option>
  <option value="3">audi</option>
```

Hope I've been clear enough!

Comment: I feel like you are going to have problems later on trying to create a unique pk using a count + 1 type system, especially when there might be deletes?

Comment: What problems could I have with deletes?

Comment: Yes thre will be problems, id collisions... With two items, 1-1 and 1-2 delete the first and count() + 1 results in 2, so the generated id will be 1-2 too, and the save will overwrite the "old" 1-2 instance with the "new" one.

Comment: If you use max+1 you shouldn't have a problem even with deletes. If you had (ignoring the categories) id's: `1 2 3` and you deleted something (e.g. `2`) before the max on your next insert you would have id's: `1 3 4`. If you deleted the max (e.g. `4`) your next insert would give you id's: `1 3 4` which keeps your id's unique. even if you deleted multiple max values (e.g. `4` and `3`) your next insert would give you id's: `1 2`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but you might want to leave your id field and instead add a category_id field instead.

```
from django.db.models import Max

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Item(models.Model):
    cat_id = models.IntegerField(editable=False, blank=True, null=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('cat_id', 'group')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.cat_id = Items.objects.filter(group=self.group).aggregate(Max('cat_id'))['cat_id__max']+1
        super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I have edited the original question adding the use case, that should explain why I don't think the proposed solution could help. Thanks anyway, I appreciated your help :)